# Dynamically added ListView not scrolling

Tags: android

I fetch JSON from HTTP server and create listviews dynamically.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                ...
                ...
                String[] lv_arr = new String[locationNames.size()];
                lv_arr = locationNames.toArray(lv_arr);

                modeList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NeighborhoodSelectActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lv_arr));
                modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        LocationDetails l = nlMap.get(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                        Intent lIntent = new Intent(NeighborhoodSelectActivity.this, LocationSelectActivity.class);
                        lIntent.putExtra("location", l);
                        startActivity(lIntent);
                    }
                });
                locationList.add(modeList);
            }
            LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.neighListLayout);
            for(ListView v : locationList) {
                lay.addView(v, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
```

The ListViews are added to the LinearLayout. But in Gingerbread and below APIs, only the last ListView is scrollable. How do I fix this?

Comment: Provide the layout XML for your codes target.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is a good idea to have multiple `ListViews` with height = `WRAP_CONTENT` in a `LinearLayout`. Is that really what you want? What about having only one `ListView` that contains all the elements? Or, if you really want them to be separate views with height = `WRAP_CONTENT`, use `LinearLayout` instead of the `ListView`.

Anyways, it would help if you could explain to us what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm fetching a list of neighborhood in a city & adding it to the list. I would like to have the City's name as the Header to the list view.

Comment: Have you checked out ExpandableListView? That is perfect for such kind of displays. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html